# Grab a String from a file at a line?

Tags: java, string, file-io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Currently, to find the line I want from the file, I am reading the file line by line until the string I'm looking for matches the current line.

This is seems like bad coding practice as my files are 1000+ lines; is there a way to tell either a scanner or buffered reader, (or something else?), to create a string from characters AT a given line?

EDIT: it appears that this isn't physically possible as ajb pointed out.

I suppose the best solution would be to read the entire file into a String[] of lines.

Comment: I don't really see any way around potentially scanning the entire file to find what you want.

Comment: Benchmark the performance in editors such as Notepad++ and you will see a lag for a file with 100K+ rows.

Comment: Unless you're on a VMS system (if there are any of those left), text files are stored as sequences of characters with `\n` or `\r\n` in between each line.  There isn't any "index" or anything to tell the system where the beginning of each line is, or any other metadata that would help speed this up.  It's sort of like if I give you a book and say "Find the 1000th 'e' in the book".  There's no way to do it except to count them all, starting from the beginning.

Comment: If you're creating the text file yourself, though, it might be possible to add an index.  If you were writing your own word processor that would be optimized to handle very large files, maybe you could consider something like this.  But you can't do this with arbitrary text files you get from anywhere.  Actually, what you'd be creating wouldn't really be a pure "text" file; it has a customized format to it, much like .docx or .odt files have their own formats.

Comment: In case you have very large files you could split a large file into multiple smaller files/blocks and employ multiple threads to do the search/matching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set an offset at which the reading or writing of the file will occur.
Use RandomAccessFile API for the same. Including a sample code below.

```
import java.io.*;

public class RandomAccessFileDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         // create a new RandomAccessFile with filename test
         RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("F:/test.txt", "r");

         System.out.println("Output without setting offset, i.e. from start of file");
         // print the lines
         String temp="";
         while((temp = raf.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(temp);

            System.out.println();
         // set the file pointer at 20 position
         raf.seek(20);
            System.out.println("Output using seek and setting offset to 20");
         // print the line
         while((temp = raf.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(temp);

      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

This is my sample test.txt placed in F drive

```
This is an example
Hello World
Trying RandomAccessFile
```

And this is the output of the program

```
Output without setting offset, i.e. from start of file
This is an example
Hello World
Trying RandomAccessFile

Output using seek and setting offset to 20
Hello World
Trying RandomAccessFile
```

Comment: How does that help find the _n_'th line?

Comment: @ajb It doesn't. The requirement in the question was to start reading after certain characters

Comment: No, you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I guess, probably so. The above piece would work if that was the requirement though. He mentioned "create string from characters AT" and I misunderstood it as read from/after certain charcters

Answer (score 0):

Try using mutli-threading concept since the number of line/rows in your file are more.

```
private void multiThreadRead(int num){

    for(int i=1; i<= num; i++) { 
        new Thread(readIndivColumn(i),""+i).start(); 
     } 
}

private Runnable readIndivColumn(final int colNum){
    return new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("From Thread no:"+colNum+" Start time:"+startTime);

                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("./src/test/test1.csv","r");
                String line = "";
                //System.out.println("From Thread no:"+colNum);

                while((line = raf.readLine()) != null){
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    //System.out.println(StatUtils.getCellValue(line, colNum));
                }


                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                String formattedTime = String.format("%d min, %d sec",  
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime), 
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime) -  
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime)) 
                    );

                System.out.println("From Thread no:"+colNum+" Finished Time:"+formattedTime);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("From Thread no:"+colNum +"===>"+e.getMessage());

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void sequentialRead(int num){
    try{
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Start time:"+startTime);

        for(int i =0; i < num; i++){
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("./src/test/test1.csv","r");
            String line = "";

            while((line = raf.readLine()) != null){
                //System.out.println(line);
            }               
        }

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        String formattedTime = String.format("%d min, %d sec",  
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime), 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime) -  
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime)) 
            );

        System.out.println("Finished Time:"+formattedTime);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
    public TesterClass() {

    sequentialRead(1);      
    this.multiThreadRead(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java NIO has a lot of new methods and simple ways of doing exactly what you want:

```
public List<String> getLinesInFile(File f){
    return Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
}
```

Or you can parse it as one massive string and search it using the contains method:

```
     /**
     * Uses static methods in the Files class of NIO
     * Reads everything in a file, and puts it in a String
     * @param file the file to read
     * @return a String representing the contents of the file
     * @throws IOException "if an I/O error occurs reading from the stream" (Files.readAllBytes javadoc)
     */
    public String readFileContents(File file) throws IOException {
        String filecontents = "";
        filecontents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI())));
        return filecontents;
    }

     /**
     * Checks if a string contains another string, ignoring case
     * @param word the string to look for
     * @param contents the string to look for the other string in
     * @return If it does contain the word, returns true. Otherwise returns false. Ignoring case.
     */
    private boolean containsIgnoreCase(String word, String contents) {
        String w = word.toLowerCase();
        String c = contents.toLowerCase();
        return c.contains(w);
    }
```